# Can OneNote online JavaScript API receive info from local program？

Tags: javascript, add-in, onenote

I want to develop a OneNote online add-in, the function including:

**1.** **Open local program** and do something like recording

**2.** When the recording is finish, the OneNote online can **receive the ending sign** and insert related image information.

I do not know if it can be implemented.

Comment: I found the solution for it.

Comment: 1. User protocol to open my UWP app
2. Use the RestApi to send my protocol to OneNote Online
new question: Online's url will add http:// for a link. currently, i use a html page to open protocol.